# What is this yellow "warning" icon appearing on a comment?

Tags: support, comments

For a very old question with a new comment there is a yellow icon.  Any idea what this means?

[image]

---

This is the answer, the comment is ... well in the comments

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14330857/215752

---

I'm using Firefox on Windows 7

Comment: ⚠️ Could be an emoji ⚠️

Comment: ⚠️ Yep, the guys above were right ⚠️. And I see it differently, depends on your browser and font. For me it's black and white and it's clear that it's part of the comment. In your image it does look like a system thingy.

Comment:  Because Unicode text is not always black and white ‎

Comment:  those comments above, they got it figured out

Comment: Well it got me... I thought it was a system thingy lol

Comment: One might even say that getting you to look twice is those symbol's gooal.  ⚽

Comment: simply looking a the source of the page would tell you what this is and how it got there. "Inspect" in the right click menu in chrome is simple enough to use.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Clicking on your upvote arrow doesn't work.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As comments above indicate, this is just an emoji that someone typed into the comment field. Specifically, [this one](https://emojipedia.org/emoji/%E2%9A%A0/). It got rendered by your system/browser as a fancy, multi-colored icon. Other systems may render it differently.

This is, unfortunately, one of the downsides of having full Unicode support—people will abuse it to post stuff like this within text. It happens on GitHub, too, where I have seen people actually using emojis in their commit summaries.

Comment: Well, what can we do we live in an *"Emoji Powered"* world.

Comment: What's wrong with people using emoji in their commit summaries? :/

Comment: `people will abuse it to post stuff like this within text` you meant *use* it, right?

Comment: [There is a solution,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji#Emoji_versus_text_presentation) but it would require inserting Unicode control characters into comment text. Also, identical rendering across different OS & browser combinations is still not guaranteed, of course.

Comment: _Abuse_, you say. But what if there were... unicorns? 

Comment: @Marvin - Most of these, what I thought was *all* of these, emojis have rendered in black and white on my chrome/win10 environment... except that freaking awesome  ! Hah, awesome. Oh, right, no fun.... your unicorn looks like unicorn. (*epic*)

Comment: @rahuldottech There are programming languages which [support emojis in variable names etc.](http://www.globalnerdy.com/2014/06/03/swift-fun-fact-1-you-can-use-emoji-characters-in-variable-constant-function-and-class-names/), so this *could* be useful in commit summaries. (But I doubt anyone is actually writing stuff like `.add()`)

Comment: @FelixSFD Forget about OOP and functional programming... Emotional programming is definitely the next hot thing!

Comment: @FelixSFD: of course, it looks much better, if the language of your choice allows to overload the “⇐ operator”: ` ⇐ `. It’s not much different to how certain languages use the `<<` and `>>`  tokens…

Comment: @TravisJ: Well, my win7/chrome at work only shows a black empty square *sadface

Comment: @Pekka웃 Abuse is appropriate for OP's example, it looks like the commenter has more authority than they actually do

Comment: "_one of the downsides of having full Unicode support—people will abuse it_" ... [What? Like this?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2096401)

Comment: @TripeHound That was back in 2009, when it was all new and shiny and the world was younger and more innocent.

Comment: @MrLister -- We need to go back to that time and make Stack Overflow Great Again (sometimes known as SOGA)

Comment: @TripeHound That is not abuse. That is regex HTML parsing cannon!